# Using if else statement in Magento email subject

Tags: email, magento, templates

I want to use an if else statement in a Magento transaction mail. Is this possible?

In the content part it works with {{if [var]}}[text]{{/if}. Is there a way to get the same logic running the subject?

Answer (score 0):

yes it should work because it goes through filter of template which process ifDirective pattern.